# Android Sliding Tabs With Material Design issue

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-actionbaractivity

I am creating a demo project for sliding tab with material design.
When I am doing like below :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity { // source code}
```

It will show red line on "**ActionBarActivity**". It is not allows for extends.
I have follow steps from http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported app compat library properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the version 22.1.0, the class [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) is deprecated. For better approach you should use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)

Just change your dependency,Like :

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, ActionBarActivity is deprecated but it should not show red lines, that is an error indication probably due to import! Use [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) introduced in support V7 library.